# 単語削除のショートカット

Tags: ruby, rubymine

参考動画のように単語上にカーソルがあった時に、何らかのショートカットを押すと
単語ごと削除できているみたいなのですが、どういった操作をしているのでしょうか？教えてください。

[参考動画]　８：２６~ 
（'あずき'　という文字を　単語ごと削除しています。）
https://youtu.be/HsivL1JBRaw?t=8m26s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vimのキーバインドを使用していると思われます。
ノーマルモードで単語の上で`ciw`と入力してみてください。

Vimキーバインドを使用しない場合のショートカットは・・・すいません、知りません。。